# R Naming plot with variable value

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate plots from a collection of files and label each plot according to the input file, my attempt is below:

```
nd_list<- lapply(nd_results,readRDS)

filenames<-as_vector(nd_results)%>%
  str_remove("_difference.RDS")

i=0 

plot_p_values<-function(nanodisco_rds){
  plot_list<-list()
  i=i+1
  plot_list[[i]]<-ggplot(nanodisco_rds,aes(t_test_pval))+ geom_histogram(bins=100)+ labs(title = filenames[i] x="T test P value")+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
}
```

My issue is that the label of each plot, which should be filenames[i], is currently "NA".

I thought it was an issue with the structure of my filenames vector but haven't been able to figure it out, the naming works later when I use ggsave to save each file according to the input file.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your code. As presented it doesn't plot anything.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_p_values<-function(nanodisco_rds, file){
  plot_list <- vector('list', length(nanodisco_rds))

  for(i in seq_along(nanodisco_rds)) {

    plot_list[[i]]<- ggplot(nanodisco_rds[[i]],aes(t_test_pval)) +  
                      geom_histogram(bins=100)+ 
                      labs(title = file[i], x="T test P value")+ 
         scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
  }
  plot_list
}

result <- plot_p_values(nd_list, filenames)
```